# Компилятор не может найти модуль (Unit) SynHighlighterPas

Tags: radstudio, delphi-10.3-rio

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(7): F2613 Unit 'SynHighlighterPas' not found.
```

Comment: А вы его найти можете или нет? Если можете - укажите и компилятору путь. Если не можете - то уберите его использование.

Comment: Пытался найти, но я не знаю  откуда Uses берет эти юниты. Когда убираю то сразу же все сыпеться т.к это готовая програма.(курсовая)

Comment: Курсовая .. пора бы уже знать что такое uses ;-) Смотрите, uses перечисляет то что нужно для сборки модуля. Получается вам надо или модуль переписать, чтобы он Syn*** не использовал (что вам явно не по плечу пока), либо найти этот SynHighlighterPas. Быстрый гуглеж по имени подсказывает, что этот модуль часть библиотеки - https://github.com/SynEdit/SynEdit

Comment: Если я скачаю этот модуль, куда мне его закинуть? Извините за такие вопросы, я просто занимался python'om, но курсовая по delphi.

Comment: Я вас отлично понимаю - новичками все когда-то были. Библиотеку надо скачать и установить (обычно в ней есть инструкции). На гитхабе, как я понимаю, лежит форк, а оригинал на sourceforge. Вот оттуда качайте и дальше гуглите - как правильно ставить библиотеки на Делфу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно скачать SynEdit в самом RAD Studio. 
Tools -> Getlt Package Manager -> Search

Comment: Только тогда это уже не Делфи-7. Поправьте метку на вопросе, чтобы было ясно о какой версии речь.